# Issue with timer event handler - Vc++

Tags: multithreading, events, visual-c++, timer

I started a new windows form in visual studio 2010 using C++ language.
There is only one timer configured to generate an event each 1ms (1milisecond)

Inside the timer event handler, I just increment a variable named Counter (who is used only in this event) and I write the current value of this variable in a textbox, so that I can see its current value.

Considering that the timer event occurs each 1ms, for each 1 second, the variable Counter should increment 1000 times, but the Counter variable takes around 15 seconds to increment 1000 times. After 15 seconds the value shown in textbox is 1000.

I set the timer event to 1ms, but seems that the event is occuring only each 15ms, because the variable Counter took 15 times (15 seconds)  more than in theory to reach the value of 1000 (1 second = 1000*1ms).

Someone have an ideia on how to solve this problem?

I need to generate an event each 1ms, where I will call another function.
How cold I generate an event each 1ms interval? Or less than this if possible.

A person of anther forum told me to create a Thread to do this job but I don't know how to do that.

Im using windows 7 profesional 64bits, I don't know if 64bits OS have any relationship with this issue. I think the PC hardware is enough to generate the event. Core 2 duo 2GHz and 3GB RAM.

http://img716.imageshack.us/img716/3627/teste1ms.png

Answer (score 0):

[System.Windows.Forms.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx) states that

**The Windows Forms Timer component is single-threaded, and is limited to an accuracy of 55 milliseconds**

So that should explain the discrepancy. Your approach seems to be a little wrong IMHO. Having a thread wake up every 1ms and that too precisely is very hard to do in a [preemptive multitasking OS.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preemption_%28computing%29)

What you can do instead is

1. Initialize a counter to zero, a high precision time variable to current time.
2. Have a timer wake you up periodically
3. When you timer fires , user a high precision timer to find current time.
4. Compute delta between new old high precision time and increment counter as much as you expect it to actually be or call some callback function that many times.

This approach will be way more precise than any timer event.